# How to efficiently select a submatrix with Python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, graph

I have an adjacency matrix of size nxn (so matrix is symmetric) and I would like to select a submatrix of size mxm and then get its upper triangle. Currently, I am doing this as follows:

```
from numpy import *
am = array([array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)])

w= (0, 1, 2, 5, 22) # select the window that consist of these nodes only
window = am[ix_(list(w),list(w))]
upper = [el for arr in [window[i][i+1:] for i in range(len(window)-1)] for el in arr]
```

But I need to perform this operation of getting the submatrix + getting its upper triangle many times, and currently this is the bottleneck of my code.

Is there any way to make this faster? If there is a way to get the upper triangle of the submatrix directly, I would also appreciate that since I don't need the full submatrix anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
w = np.array((0, 1, 2, 5, 22))
n = len(w)
rang = np.arange(n, 0, -1)
rows = np.repeat(w, rang)
col_idx  = np.arange(n * (n + 1) // 2)
delta = np.repeat(np.concatenate(([0], np.cumsum(rang[1:]))),
                  rang)
col_idx -= delta
cols = np.take(w, col_idx)
```

And now:

```
>>> rows
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  5,  5, 22])
>>> cols
array([ 0,  1,  2,  5, 22,  1,  2,  5, 22,  2,  5, 22,  5, 22, 22])
>>> am[rows, cols]
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually just realized that instead of the adj. matrix, I can look at adj. list and extract the submatrix from there. Since the adj. matrix is very sparse in my case (only a couple of elements are non-zero), it will speed up things much more. However, I couldn't figure out how I can extract the submatrix from an adj. list instead of a adj. matrix.. I posted the question here in case you might want to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833811/how-to-select-a-submatrix-from-an-adjacency-list-in-python Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try [numpy.triu](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) (triangle-upper) and numpy.tril (triangle-lower).

Comment: i tried triu before, but then since it is returning the full matrix with just lower triangle is zeroed-out, i wrote my own code to get the upper triangle (i need a flattened list of the upper triangle). however, even if i use triu; i need to select the submatrix first.

Comment: Are all the elements of the upper triangle non-zero?

Comment: they can be either 0 or 1, but not necessarily all non-zeros.