# How to select a submatrix from an adjacency list in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, graph

I have an adjacency list where each array represents non-zero columns at that row (e.g. 0th array in the adj. list below means columns 2 and 6 are 1, and everything else is 0).

> adj_list = [[2, 6], [1, 3, 24], [2, 4], [3, 5, 21], [4, 6, 10], [1, 5,
>   7], [6, 8, 9], [7], [7, 10, 14], [5, 9, 11], [10, 12, 18], [11, 13],
>   [12, 14, 15], [9, 13], [13, 16, 17], [15], [15], [11, 19, 20], [18],
>   [18], [4, 22, 23], [21], [21], [2, 25, 26], [24], [24]]

Given this adj. list, I would like to select a submatrix which has identical row and column indices that is given by:

```
submatrix = (0, 1, 2, 5, 22)
```

Each element in submatrix indicates a row number.

1) For each row `i` in submatrix, I need to get `ith` array from  `adj_list` (which is equivalent to getting `ith` row from an adjacency matrix)

2) Then from that array, I need to extract the items that match with submatrix

For example, if I am currently looking at 3rd element in `submatrix`, which is 5, then I need to go to 5th array in adj_list (equivalent of getting 5th row of adj.matrix), which is [1,5,7], and then I need to look which elements in [1,5,7] matches with submatrix (equivalent of getting 1th, 5th and 7th columns of the 5th row). In this case, the result for 5th row should be [0,1,0,1,0] because only 1 and 5 are intersected in two arrays).

How can I efficiently select this submatrix given the adj. list?

Comment: Your question is not really clear to me, what do you mean with 'a submatrix given by (0, 1, 2, 5, 22)' ? Could you give the exact result you expect?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I updated the question. Basically, I converted an adjacency matrix into an adjacency list. And submatrix encodes which rows and columns I want to extract from the adjacency matrix (for example, I need to select 0th, 1st, 2nd, 5th, 22nd rows and from each of that rows I need to select 0th, 1st, 2nd, 5th, 22nd columns).

Comment: Solving this problem isnt too hard, but depending on your further plans and needs, I would take a look at scipy.sparse, or one of the excellent graph libraries available. That could save you reinventing a lot of wheels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
adj_list = [[2, 6], [1, 3, 24], [2, 4], [3, 5, 21], [4, 6, 10], [1, 5, 7], [6, 8, 9], [7], [7, 10, 14], [5, 9, 11], [10, 12, 18], [11, 13], [12, 14, 15], [9, 13], [13, 16, 17], [15], [15], [11, 19, 20], [18], [18], [4, 22, 23], [21], [21], [2, 25, 26], [24], [24]]

submatrix = (0, 1, 2, 5, 22)

result = [[i in adj_list[sm] for i in submatrix] for sm in submatrix]
```

This should do it; though I suspect you might prefer to compute something other than this if you consider your end goal more carefully.

Comment: thanks for your answer. my end goal is getting the upper triangle of "result" array, so i actually don't need to look at half of the matrix since its symmetric. right now, i am getting its upper triangle as result=[map(int, [i in am[sm] for i in submatrix]) for sm in submatrix] upper = [el for arr in [result[i][i+1:] for i in range(len(result)-1)] for el in arr] but i am wondering if there is a way to directly getting this upper triangle without computing "result" array first.